# Can I get the question id in the inbox route?

Tags: support, api-v2.2, inbox, notifications

My intended behavior of my app is to navigate the user the the question page when an inbox item gets clicked.

For example, when the API return a link like this
`https://stackapps.com/questions/8515/after-which-time-span-can-my-vote-no-longer-change/8517#8517` I navigate in my app to `questions/8515/after-which-time-span-can-my-vote-no-longer-change/8517#8517` and everything works fine.
Here I can simply use the question id `8515` to navigate to the question and `8517#8517` to highlight the answer.

To come to my problem now. 
When I use the `inbox` route I'm interested in two `item_type`s :

- new_answer
- comment

Both contain a *link* that for me is hard to use, because they don't contain the question id. e.g.:

- `https://stackapps.com/a/8517?noredirect=1` (item_type: new_answer)
- `https://stackapps.com/posts/comments/17601?noredirect=1` (item_type: comment)

Is there any way to figure out the *question id* of the answer / comment without making another request like [answers by ids](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-by-ids#filter=!SWJ_U*(icXTT70ePdT)?

Comment: To find the question an answer belongs, [use the question by answer ids](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-answer-ids) method (find `question_id`). To find a post where a comment belongs, [use the comment by ids](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/comments-by-ids) method (find `post_id`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can – *sometimes*. The default filter contains a `question_id` field, and according to the examples for the [`inbox_item` type](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/inbox-item) (you have to scroll down a bit) it is filled in some situations. I just tested it and the notification for [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341532/what-happens-if-a-bounty-is-awarded-automatically-when-there-are-2-answers-with?noredirect=1#comment1142641_341532) looks like this:

[image]

It should be populated for the `new_answer` type as well, but I couldn't test this quickly. It is *not* populated for notifications about comments to your *answers*; then, only the `answer_id` field is filed.